# JQuery Mobile - transition fails when ajax is disabled

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have two `data-role="page"` divs, "content" and "links".
Content is the default page, with a button for displaying links:

```
<a data-role="button" href="#links" data-transition="slide">More</a>
```

If `$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnable = false` then the following is broken:

1. It does not link to a bookmark on the same page. i.e. it links from example.com/randompage.html to example.com/#links
2. The transition (slide) fails **even** if I add `data-ajax="true"` to the anchor.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Example for SO</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="content"> 
    <a data-role="button" href="#links" data-ajax="true" data-transition="slide">More</a> 
    Text here
</div> 
<div data-role="page" id="links"> 
    <a data-role="button" href="" data-rel="back">Back</a> 
    <div>A bunch of extra links here</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

P.S.
I'm realizing that this may be a library bug, and not my fault.

**Edit**: Live example link has been removed.

Comment: Does the AJAX call work/respond correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. "#links" isn't an ajax-loaded page, it's a div on the same page

Comment: could you edit your question and post the basic page layout?

Comment: Phill, I added the basic layout info

Comment: hmm, I tested you code locally and all seems to work as expected. What exactly is the problem? Also could you use jsfiddle.net for you example as they blocked the other site here at work

Comment: Phill, the error presents itself when you set `ajaxLinksEnabled = false`; jsfiddle does not have a filename for my code so this bug is not present (read issue 1)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the data-url attribute to the page div. Even if the page is normally loaded using ajax, the presence of that attribute tells the framework that the requested url is already on the page and doesn't need to be loaded again.

You may also need data-dom-cache to prevent the page from being removed when it is hidden.

Comment: I think the problem isn't with the `links` div. It's with the `More` button. If you go to the example page and add `#links` by hand -- it will transition

Comment: Possibly, but clicking on a link with lots of javascript attached isn't the same as opening the url from href directly. Try `href="/links.html"` on your link and `data-url="/links.html" data-dom-cache="true"` on the page div. That should get you the result you are expecting, but through a different path so not subject to the same issues.